# Drupal 7 -Netscaler -Cookies

Tags: php, drupal, session-cookies

We are attempting to provide access through Netscaler-CVPN for a  Drupal 7 web application 
but  the server is not allowing the login. And we got this:

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: SSESSa5239a81fce10b404a57573e10af7bef=v8HAWDup-youPSJ-ozzcPX325W9NWBlfF8QezbadpXU; expires=Sat, 19-May-2018 16:32:18 GMT; Max-Age=2000000; path=/; domain=.mymuhc.dev.muhc.mcgill.ca; secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://mywebo.ca/users/jata6003
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

GET /users/jatpp6093 HTTP/1.1
Host: mymuhc.dev.muhc.mcgill.ca
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https:// mywebo.ca/user/login
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: identity

As you see the Cookie is not  set